# Can cabal/stack/nix be used to compile into dynamic library?

Tags: haskell, cabal, ffi, haskell-stack, nix

I'm trying to build shared library containing exported ffi code into shared library. I wonder if it is possible to do it with common tools like stack or nix (so basically with cabal)? **Is it? Then how?**

https://github.com/bennoleslie/haskell-shared-example contains good example of such code, but with manual build instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .cabal file stanza you're looking for is `foreign-library`. The [documentation](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-package.html?highlight=foreign#foreign-libraries) describes it very well.

As for nix, if you use [`haskell.nix`](https://github.com/input-output-hk/haskell.nix), a derivation for the foreign library will be exposed under `<binding>.components.foreignlibs.<libname>`.

To build with `cabal2nix`, run

```sh
cabal2nix . > default.nix
nix-build -E '(import <nixpkgs> {}).haskellPackages.callPackage ./default.nix {}'
```

Your shared library will be under `result/lib/ghc-<version>/<your-lib>.(so|dll|dylib)`.

Comment: I saw this chapter name, but I thought it is about embedding external libraries in the project 

Comment: I'm not able to find anything similar in result of cabal2 nix. may it not be there?

Comment: Updated answer to add cabal2nix version